# Insert text programmatically at caret position in WPF DataGrid cell when shortcut is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridtextcolumn

How do I insert text at caret position in DataGridTextColumn when the user press Alt+X?

This is the DataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TheGrid" SelectionUnit="Cell" ItemsSource="{Binding Soruce}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I have tried a to make my own CellEditingTemplate and CellTemplate. But when I do it like that it messes up the Tab-functionality of the grid. I have to double or tripple-tab to edit the next cell.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"></TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Code behind. You cannot insert the text in directly to the databound model since you have to know the caret position.

```
    private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
      //Insert text at caret position
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a style that adds an EventSetter on the EditingElementStyle for the KeyDown-event.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TheGrid" SelectionUnit="Cell" ItemsSource="{Binding Soruce}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="TextBox_KeyDown" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Then add the event handler to the code behind. Insert the text on the SelectedText porperty to get familiar behaviour and then move the carret to after the inserted text.

```
    private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SystemKey == Key.X && Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Alt))
        {
            string text = "Text to insert";
            TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
            textBox.SelectedText = text;
            textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.SelectionStart + text.Length;
            textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
    }
```